# How should I approach tslint no-null-keyword on frontend?

Tags: javascript, typescript, null, eslint, tslint

I've enabled tslint in my project. I've also added [no-null-keyword](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-null-keyword/) to my configs. I'm using node.js so I'm using typescript on both frontend and backend. So on backend no-null-keyword is not a problem. I can change all the nulls to undefined easily but when it comes to front end the system is using null as default which makes it hard for me to from null to undefined.

For example `localStorage.getItem(nicknameId)` returns `string | null`

Many other functions return a possible null and not undefined in [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts).

```
readonly firstElementChild: Element | null;
readonly lastElementChild: Element | null;
readonly nextElementSibling: Element | null;
readonly previousElementSibling: Element | null;
```

My best idea is only using this rule on the backend. But then the frontend will have both nulls & undefineds which will increase chances of bugs. So how should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you cannot strictly null-check it like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem(nicknameId) !== null)
```

you can falsey-check it like this instead:

```
if (localStorage.getItem(nicknameId))
```

In case the above doesn't work because of `0`, `''`, etc., you can loosely check against `undefined` (this 'catches' both `undefined` AND `null`):

```
if (localStorage.getItem(nicknameId) != undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

In our project we use a method to check for both `undefined` and `null` that we use instead of truthy/falsy-checks and direct checks against `undefined` and `null`, unless there is a semantic difference ofc.:

```
export function isPresent<T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T {
    return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}
```

This method would be used like this

```
if(isPresent(localStorage.getItem(nicknameId))) {...}
```